# (Noob) Is giving root-only permission to hide python script good?

Tags: linux, security, python, smtp

I don't want people to see my python script and my searches tell me that it's not really possible, but will setting the python script read access to root-only work? Is there a downside to this?

The program would run as root at startup and in the background, sending e-mails on conditions. The email part needs a user and a password to be sent to the SMTP. I want to protect those credentials.

Comment: Are you trying to hide it from your self? Can you set up another user account (for running this script, not associated with a person)?

Comment: I would change the question to: I am trying to ... [this is already in your question], I would like to protect the smtp credentials from ... How can I do that? (don't preempt with solutions, except to say this is what I have tried / thought about, but it does-not / won't work because of ...

Answer (score 1):

Hiding a password in a text file gives a limited amount of security, but yes this is still a small improvement.

After all unix passwords are also stored, but salted, in /etc/shadow.

Remember that if people have access to the computer and boot for instance a live CD, since they are root inside the live cd environment, they will be able to read any file on your computer.

Comment: It would be on a Raspberry pi. So if they have physical access to it they could bypass the root protection? Is it easy to break or would the hacker need to be advanced?

Comment: Basic knowledge: pull out SD card, plug it in to another machine. Done. It would have to run Linux (MS can't read ext file-system).

Answer (score 0):

By changing the owner to root and removing all access to other users and groups you can effectively ensure your script will not be read by anyone who does not have root access.

You can accomplish this by running the following two commands.

The first will ensure only the owner of the file (root) has permission to read and execute the script `chmod 500 script.py`

*(If you need to be able to write the file as well you can use `chmod 700 script.py` but we generally want to follow the rule of least privilege when we can.)*

The second command will make root the owner of the script
`sudo chown root:root script.py`

At this point nobody except for root will be able to read, write, or execute your script. Keep in mind then when users run `sudo` they are operating as the root user.